# Ignore entity properties only for select queries. But still consider them during update/insert. EF Core 2.1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have the following question:
I have about 80 DBSets in Ef Context. All these entities are inherited from HistoricalEntity class which contains historical fields like (AddDate, AddSource, ChangeDate, ChangeSource). I want to find a solution how to not select these fields in each query. Is there a way to do it once and globally? Something like to set Global query filter?

Also, I tried to use NotMapped attribute and Fluent API Method Ignore, but in these cases Update and Insert operations for historical properties are prevented.

Other words, I don't want to select historical fields in all queries but I still want to update and insert them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you can use 'Entity Framework Dynamic Filters' that is a library that Creates global and scoped filters for Entity Framework queries.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately they don't support ef core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core has [Shadow Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)

> Shadow properties are properties that are not defined in your .NET
>   entity class but are defined for that entity type in the EF Core
>   model. The value and state of these properties is maintained purely in
>   the Change Tracker.

Comment: Hey David, maybe you know how to to do the following thing: I want to EF by default don't include in all select queries my historical properties. I make them like Shadow Properties, and now they doesn't mapped to my entity, but I still see in DB profiler that shadow properties included in all select queries. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want them at all, set them to NotMapped, or exclude them from your Entities entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Maybe I just do things in a strange way...But I need these fields  - I override SaveChanges and set values to my historical fields only on Add and Update(like who did this chnages, from which source system, when and so on). But I dont want to select them all the time

Comment: "But I dont want to select them all the time" why?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how sql server works. But as I understand for sql server it is an additional work, additional reads to select these fields in each query and subquery. And for example, If I will decide to create some index for some table I would see "table look up" in the execution plan because of my queries by default select historical fields as well. So maybe I wrong but I preffered not to select the, rather than select. For exapmle on the screenshot, you can see how many fields could be selected in 1 query without any purpose : https://www.screencast.com/t/tuAJHpNTNG

Comment: That typically wouldn't make a significant performance difference.

Comment: I need property not to be in select queries because I am using the property for a foreign key which is not the primary key on the principal and which does not exist in the principal table, it's the property that indicates the type of principal, and I don't want to store that same value in every row for principal table. A dependant table is a generic table for multiple principal types. e.g. Schools table that has many People, or Exams that has many People, People table has column EntityTypeId and EntityId as foreign keys.

Comment: This should be a new question.